# shows incompatible version for your android mobile

Tags: android, sdk, version

For my application min sdk version is 11 and target sdk version is 17. but still it shows this app incompatible for android 4.0 and android 4.2
what might be the issue ??

check this link..
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=spy.cam.unibera

Comment: `but still it shows this app incompatible for android 4.0` where it shows it?

Comment: on google playstore itself.... when i search with link on my phone

Comment: check if you do not require speciall things like phone, camera, ... etc (`<uses-feature>`) ...

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> i have used only these two features ;(

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#required ... default is true

Comment: Posting the manifest file would be relevant for diagnosing such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have added `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />` Google play will filter the device which doesn't support camera auto focus feature. Example : Samsung galaxy mini does not have auto focus feature.

try adding  `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>`

Note : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`  which by default include auto focus feature true, so you have to add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>` if you use that too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run a lint check for  API's?

May be you are using a android API method/class somewhere which is not available in Android 4.0/4.2.

Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) to know about about lint. There are other resources available too, just look around.

Comment: lint check ? how would i do that

Comment: its a simple camera app, and apk itself contains android 4.2.2

Comment: updated answer. you should always do a lint check once.. it helps a lot

Comment: If you are using eclipse, you will see Run Android lint after AVD manager

Comment: M NOT FINDING A WAY TO START A LINT CHECK ;(